# ¿Hacer que XPATH devuelva listas de listas? [ [ ] , [ ] , [ ] ]

Tags: javascript, html, web, scraping, xpath

Estoy aprendiendo a usar XPATH, y quiero recoger una lista de los nombres.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nombres</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="contenedor_total">
            <div class="nombres">
                <a href="#">Pedro</a>
                <a href="#">José</a>
                <a href="#">Maria</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nombres">
                <a href="#">Arturo</a>
                <a href="#">Martha</a>
                <a href="#">Luis</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nombres">
                <a href="#">Carlos</a>
                <a href="#">Sergio</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nombres">
                <a href="#">Sandra</a>
                <a href="#">Enrique</a>
                <a href="#">Arturo</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Entonces, lo que debería hacer es poner el siguiente código

```js
$x("//div[@class='contenedor_total']/div[@class='nombres']/text()")
```

Y me devuelve la siguiente lista:

```
[Pedro,José,Maria,Arturo,Martha,Luis,Carlos,Sergio,Sandra,Enrique,Arturo]
```

Sin embargo no quiero que me lo devuelva así, sino que me devuelva una lista de listas de cada `div`, así:

```
[[Pedro,José,Maria],[Arturo,Martha,Luis],[Carlos,Sergio],[Sandra,Enrique,Arturo]]
```

**¿Qué debo hacer para que me devuelva eso?, o ¿No se puede?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad, hay varias versiones de XPath, 1.0 del año 1999, 2.0 de 2007 o 2008, y 3.0 de 2014 (creo) y la versión actual, 3.1 del año 2017.

Además, XPath mismo no tiene el concepto de listas, en XPath 1.0 solo se conoce el concepto de valores atómicos como números o strings y una cantidad de nodos, en XPath 2 o 3 o 3 se ha generalizado ese concepto a secuencias de valores, tanto atómicos como nodos, pero no se conoce secuencias de secuencias. Sin embargo, en XPath 3.1 además tenemos la opción de un "array" (he utilizado la palabra inglesa de la especificación de XPath 3.1 aquí) y se permite formar arrays de arrays y secuencias de arrays y arrays de secuencias.

Lo que tu has utilizado, me parece, es XPath 1.0 en el entorno de JavaScript (lo creo por el uso de `$x`) y el resultado que consideras una lista no es realmente una lista de XPath sino un array de JavaScript (con un poco mágia de la función `$x`). En JavaScript es posible crear arrays de arrays, sin embargo, no existen expresiones únicas de XPath 1.0 para crearlos.

Afortunadamente, con JavaScript, tanto en en navegador como con Node.js, hay una implementación de XPath 3.1 en la forma de Saxon-JS 2 (https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml), que sí permite formar XPath arrays de arrays o arrays de secuencias y devolverlos a JavaScript.

Te doy un ejemplo:

```js
//var SaxonJS = require("saxon-js") // solo fuera del navegador con Node.js

const xml = `<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nombres</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="contenedor_total">
            <div class="nombres">
                <a href="#">Pedro</a>
                <a href="#">José</a>
                <a href="#">Maria</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nombres">
                <a href="#">Arturo</a>
                <a href="#">Martha</a>
                <a href="#">Luis</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nombres">
                <a href="#">Carlos</a>
                <a href="#">Sergio</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nombres">
                <a href="#">Sandra</a>
                <a href="#">Enrique</a>
                <a href="#">Arturo</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>`;

SaxonJS.getResource({ type: 'xml', text: xml }).then(doc => {
  const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(
    `//div[@class = 'nombres']!array { data(a) }`, doc);
  console.log(result);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```

En tu comentario mencionas que utilizas Python y lxml, entonces trata

```
result = [div.xpath('a[@href]/text()') for div in html.fromstring(respuesta.text).xpath('//div[@class = "nombres"]')]
```

Comment: Gracias, no sabía lo de las versiones de XPATH, pero estoy usando Python con la librería lxml.html. `html.fromstring(respuesta.text).xpath("//div[@class='contenedor_total']/div[@class='nombres']/text()")`.

Comment: No entiendo por qué tu pregunta muestra `$x` y entonces dices que utilizas Python y lxml. lxml solo soporta XPath 1.0, como escribí, en esta versión no es posible formular una sola expresión de XPath para conseguir el resultado. Para utilizar XPath 3.1 con Python, podrías utilizar Saxon-C en lugar de Saxon-JS, Saxon-C (https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml) tiene interfaz para Python 3. Sin embargo, podrías también utilizar lxml con Python y comprensión de listas para conseguir el resultado.

Comment: Gracias amigo, tienes razón, no especifiqué que era Python, es que pensé que no era necesario porque no sabía lo de las versiones de XPATH